# SimpleCursorAdapter: вытащить строку по ид

Tags: cursor, android

Использовал в своем приложении кусок кода от библиотеки [Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

И там я использую TabPager вместе с ListView. Мне нужно реализовать при нажатии на элемент ListView открывается поле позволяющее изменять текст этого элемента.

Вот собственно код класса. Первый раз вижу SimpleCursorAdapter поэтому даже не понимаю как он работает и с чем его есть.

```
// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
```

а тут создание этого объекта

```
   mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
            new String[] { MainTable.COLUMN_NAME_DATA },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

А вот собственно и тут нужно как-то вытащить строку

```
        **@Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Insert desired behavior here.
            Log.i(TAG, "Item clicked: " + id);
               //тут нужно что-то сделать типа
               String s=????
        }
```

как вытащить строку по ид из adaptera в методе OnListItemClick?

пробую вытащить так:

```
String s=(String)(l.getAdapter().getItem(position));
```

Выдает:

```
7-22 15:09:24.301: E/AndroidRuntime(11730): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

а потом как сделать так чтоб открылось не новое активити, а вспомогательное окно с одним текстовым полем вот например как в навигаторе гугл когда нажимаешь кнопку "Домой" основное окно как бы становится на задний план, а на окне появляется одно текстовое поле. вот пример в гугл навигаторе

http://www.wiseguys.com.ua/edtitext.png

**UPD:
Проблема решена**

1) Вот собственно как получить текст или ид в базе через ListView в методе OnListClickItem

> Cursor cursor = (Cursor)
> l.getItemAtPosition(position);
>
> ```
>          // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
>          int Id = 
>           Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainTable._ID)));
>          Log.i("ff",String.valueOf(Id));
> ```

получить текст

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
              String s = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MainTable._TEXT));
```

2) вот как реализовал AlertDialog

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
```

Comment: ну все просто! только input у тебя где, до или после кнопок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Можно заранее составить массив списка и Вытаскивать по позиций нажатия.

   ```
   list_array[position]
   ```
2. Можно либо открыть диалог либо новый актвити только в манифесте задать тему диалога

   ```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
   ```
3. Вызов и обработка диалога

   ```
   //константы
       private static final int ID_FIRST_DIALOG  = 0;
   private static final int ID_SECOND_DIALOG = 1;

   //вызов
   showDialog(ID_FIRST_DIALOG);

   //обработка
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   switch (id) {
   case ID_FIRST_DIALOG:
       builder.setMessage(
               "Вопрос диалога что вы хотите сделать")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("название первой кнопки",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               // то что вы делаете при нажатий этой кнопки
                           }
                       })
               .setNeutralButton("Вторая кнопка",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                               // действие по второй кнопке
                           }
                       })
               .setNegativeButton("кнопка отмены и закрытия диалога",
                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                   int id) {
                               dialog.cancel();
                           }
                       });
       return builder.create();
   case ID_SECOND_DIALOG:
       // если нужен еще один диалог
       return builder.create();
   default:
       return null;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: благодарю. А как в такой dialog добавить текстовое поле?

Comment: Текстовое поле незнаю, не юзал.  position - это номер позиции в списке. Откуда вы берете данные в адаптер и что это за данные? Я использовал новый активите с темой диалог, тогда можно насторить как угодно и сколько угодно текстовых полей. Вид тот же получаеться.

Comment: я уже изменил вопрос, там добавил откуда я беру адаптер.

Comment: по поводу диалога, пользуйте не AlertDialog  а обычный Dialog. разметку можете сами создать. И При создании диалога присвоить ему Layout файл. Такой вариант более гибкий чем тот, что вы описали у себя же в вопросе

Comment: Павел, да, диалог как выяснилось более гибкое решение. потому что возникла необходимость кроме кнопок ок cancel добавить кнопку delete